# error while downloading BLAS,LAPACK and ALS libraries through MinGw terminal

Tags: java, mingw, ipopt

I am compiling Installation of java IPOPT under Win8 64bit. for that I have done Installation of MSYS/MinGW. I am following the instructions given at lower section of this link:

https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node15.html

Now I want to install some libraries through terminal of MinGw:

https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node13.html

But I am getting errors while passing some commands in shell e.g.

```
$ cd $IPOPTDIR/ThirdParty/Blas 
$ ./get.Blas 
$ cd ../Lapack 
$ ./get.Lapack 
$ cd ../ASL 
$ ./get.ASL
```

It give me errors like `command not found` or `No such file or directory`. I do not understand how can I install these libraries via shell? Can someone help me? I have no idea about shell scripting. Thanks in advance.